# Get multiple XML records in one table from a repeated element and its subelements \ attributes

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

Present algorithm uses ... ,x.n.value ... [1]  method which retrieves only first records. What is better to use to retrieve all existed element's values (and the other records down the hierarchy)?

The primary XML extraction is based on a model like

```
SELECT..
CAST(decompress([Data]) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

FROM..
```

then goes:

```
 ;WITH XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT 'urn://somenamespacename')
  INSERT INTO  [DB].[dbo].[table] (

ID
,Att1
,Att2
,SubAtt1
,SubAtt2
,Lenght
,Neighbour

)

SELECT

@ID
,x.n.value('(@Att1)[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)')
,x.n.value('(@Att2)[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)')
,x.n.value('(*:Neighbours/*:SubBorder/@SubAtt1)[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)')
,x.n.value('(*:Neighbours/*:SubBorder/@SubAtt2)[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)')
,x.n.value('(*:Edge/*:Lenght)[1]', 'int')
,x.n.value('(*:Edge/*:Neighbour)[1]',  'VARCHAR(100)')

FROM @xml.nodes('/root/*:TOP/*:Border')  as x(n)
```

**XML sample**

```
<root>
    <TOP ID="1">
     <Border Att1="BorderValue1" Att2="BorderValue2">
       <Edge>
         <Length>100</Length>
         <Neighbours>
           <Neighbour>alpha</Neighbour>
           <SubBorder SubAtt1="SubValue1" SubAtt2="SubValue2" />
         </Neighbours>
       </Edge>
      </Border>

      <Border Att1="BorderValue3" Att1="BorderValue4">
       <Edge>
         <Length>300</Length>
         <Neighbours>
           <Neighbour>bravo</Neighbour>
           <SubBorder SubAtt1="SubValue3" SubAtt2="SubValue4" />
         </Neighbours>
       </Edge>
      </Border>
    </TOP>
</root>
```

**Desired output**

```
ID      Att1          Att2         SubAtt1    SubAtt2    Lenght    Neighbour       
 1   BorderValue1 BorderValue2    SubValue1  SubValue2   100        alpha
 1   BorderValue3 BorderValue4    SubValue3  SubValue4   300        bravo
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are declaring a namespace, but there is no namespace part of the XML...
Furthermore, there is a doubled attribute "Att1", which is a typo assumably

However, it seems you are looking for `.nodes()`. This function retrieves repeated elements in a derived table:

Your XML (without a namespace):

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
N'<root>
    <TOP ID="1">
     <Border Att1="BorderValue1" Att2="BorderValue2">
       <Edge>
         <Length>100</Length>
         <Neighbours>
           <Neighbour>alpha</Neighbour>
           <SubBorder SubAtt1="SubValue1" SubAtt2="SubValue2" />
         </Neighbours>
       </Edge>
      </Border>

      <Border Att1="BorderValue3" Att2="BorderValue4">
       <Edge>
         <Length>300</Length>
         <Neighbours>
           <Neighbour>bravo</Neighbour>
           <SubBorder SubAtt1="SubValue3" SubAtt2="SubValue4" />
         </Neighbours>
       </Edge>
      </Border>
    </TOP>
</root>';
```

--The query

```
SELECT @xml.value('(/root/TOP/@ID)[1]','int') AS ID
      ,brd.value('@Att1','nvarchar(max)') AS Att1
      ,brd.value('@Att2','nvarchar(max)') AS Att2
      ,brd.value('(Edge/Length/text())[1]','decimal(10,4)') AS [Length]
      ,nghbs.value('(Neighbour/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS Border_Neighbour
      ,nghbs.value('(SubBorder/@SubAtt1)[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS Border_SubAtt1
      ,nghbs.value('(SubBorder/@SubAtt2)[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS Border_SubAtt2
FROM @xml.nodes('root/TOP/Border') ATU_2x_check(brd)
OUTER APPLY brd.nodes('Edge/Neighbours') B(nghbs);
```

The idea in short:

- We can pick the ID directly (is not repeating)
- We use `.nodes()` to get repeating `<Border>` elements
- We can dive deeper into repeating `<Neighbours>` using `.nodes()` with a relative XPath
- We can use `.value()` to read the values out of given fragments.

Comment: @ShnugoThank you! Do I understand correctly that for the correct parsing of all elements it is enough to make outer apply with the lowest elements in the hierarchy? In this case, you do not need an additional outer apply (as here, for example, with the `Length` element)

Comment: is there a significant difference between usual construction `'.value...nvarchar(max)')` and construction `(/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)`? I tried both options, the results are the same.

Comment: @XSLT-explorer, you need nodes() to retrieve repeated nodes as derived set and you do not need it for single values (any singleton xpath relative to the current node). And /text() will speed up the query and you need it in cases like this: `<a>a1<b>inner</b>a2</a>`. `a1` and `a2` are different text nodes below `<a>`